# CRM 2011 - Decreasing "Maximum Length" of the Subject field in Appointment Gives an error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, appointment

When I want to decrease the "Maximum Length" of the "Subject"-field on appointment, it gives me the following error :

> Updating RecurringAppointmentMaster.subject.Length but it's
>   not valid for update. Original value:400. New value:398.

We can't import a managed solution into CRM 2011 because the subject on the managed solution is "255" and we use "200" as maximum length for the "Subject"-field. Is there something we can do to adjust the size (maybe trough unsupported DB-handling)?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always modify managed solution... totally unsupported though but I would say it's the lesser of two unsupported evils here :)

Comment: The managed solution is not ours :) I guess this is a microsoft bug?